# Cache a dataset in Vega-lite or Vega-embed

Tags: vega, vega-lite

I have a use case that a user can create different visualizations with a single dataset in a trial-and-error fashion. Is it possible to cache the loaded and parsed dataset in Vega to increase performance?

**Update:**

According to @dominik's answer, I tried to put the data inline as a JavaScript object. However, it seems Vega-lite still parses the data, which costs a lot of time. The spec I used is shown below, which shows the data is indeed inline.

[image: The Vega-lite spec with inline data]

The screenshot of Chrome's profiling tool shows that the `parse` function takes most of the time.

[image: The stack shown in Chrome's profiling tool]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not out of the box because there aren't any guarantees that the data does not change. However, you can read the dataset outside of Vega and then pass it either inline in the spec or through the view API.

Comment: In my case, I am guaranteeing the data is not changed. When I pass the data inline with the spec, it will still "parse" it, right? Is it possible to skip the "parse" step? Maybe by reimplementing the underlying pipeline?

Comment: Vega-Lite just passed the reference to Vega so there is no overhead. Just make sure you pass in a JavaScript object with the types as close to what you need (e.g. strings parsed as numbers, ...).

Comment: That's a good point. In that case, I should make sure the JavaScript object follows Vega's format. How do I read/parse a dataset (e.g. a csv file) into a JavaScript object that follows Vega's format? Does Vega/D3/Vega-Embed provide such API?

Comment: It's an array with objects. Any CSV parser such as D3 or datalib will work.

Comment: Inlining the data doesn't seem to help. I edited the question to show the profiling results. It seems that Vega-lite decides to parse the data no matter what.

Comment: Vega-Lite computes a hash so that when two branches of the dataflow use the same data, they get merged. I didn't know you're asking about Vega-Lite.

One solution is to insert the data via the view API after you compile the spec. Regardless, if you could file an issue about the hashing, I can make it faster.

Comment: Bug report created: https://github.com/vega/vega-lite/issues/4146#issue-354491476. As I am not familiar with the internals of Vega-Lite, I am not sure what you mean by merging two branches of dataflow (what benefits does it bring?). For the view API suggestion, does it mean I use a dummy dataset for the Vege-Lite spec and insert the data later?

Comment: This has been fixed in the latest version.